# redirecting a user to nearest server for a file based on ip

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have an intranet site running on windows 2003 and on a page I have training video posted. we have three locations and three servers, the training videos have been placed on each server in a folder. What I would like to do is when someone clicks on a video link I would like for the IP to be checked and have the person sent to the file that is in their area.

Each area has its own range of IP's so if there was a way to check if it falls within a range and forward the person to the appropriate server and file it would be great. I am trying to avoid having to create a list of all the videos 3 times (one list for each area) and saying if your in this area click on these video and so forth. I have been looking for a solution for a couple of days and have not found what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these Windows file shares that the videos are hosted on?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like these are Windows file shares that the videos are hosted on. If that's the case, you want to use a combination of [DFS Namespaces and DFS-Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127250.aspx) along with [Active Directory Sites and Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730868.aspx) to make this work.

You would make a common namespace that has three files shares behind it. For example `\\domain\shares\video` would actually have three shares behind it, one for each server, and clients can be redirected to the correct server transparently based on what site they're currently in. That site location awareness is handled by site and subnet objects created in AD Sites and Services.

Comment: the intranet was created using dotnetnuke which is running on windows 2003 server. I was thinking of more like a script I can add on the web page to do what I need but not sure if it can be done. If someone is local and they click on a video it would open the local file but if they are not local it would open the file on the server in their area based on IP. I know DFS can be an option but the boss seems to be looking for something outside of DFS..Any other ideas? THANK YOU for your response MDMarra:)

Comment: If you're using a custom website to distribute these videos, you'll need to add custom code to it. It shouldn't be too difficult to write in some logic that looks at the IP making the request and returns different files based on pre-defined subnets.

Comment: Yeah the only programming I am OK with is JS but I just cant create anything to check the IP but it may be beyond my skill level. I was hoping to find something I could at least modify so I wouldn't have to create from scratch.

Comment: Anyone have an idea where I can find some code that does some of what I need so I can at least modify and not have to start from scratch? I still have had no luck finding anything that does not require the use of server side script as well.